# Reaching static variables in C++

Tags: c++, static

If I define a static variable in classA:

```
static int m_val;
```

and initialize like

```
int classA::m_val = 0;
```

Can I use directly m_val as it is in order to access it in ClassA (or any other class) or should I use it like classA::m_val.

Comment: classA::m_val everywhere except within classA

Comment: Inside classA it is sufficient to write m_val.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of `ClassA`, just write `m_val`. Outside of `ClassA`, `ClassA::m_val`.

However, `m_val` is not `const` in your example, so it (typically) should be **private** anyway. In that case, you'd not access it directly from other classes but provide a member function to retrieve a copy:

```
class ClassA
{
private:
    static int m_val;
// ...
public:
    static int GetVal();
};
```

Implementation:

```
int ClassA::m_val = 0;

int ClassA::GetVal()
{
    return m_val;
}
```